# Will using Slow negatively affect my score?

Tags: touhou-embodiment-of-scarlet-devil

While playing *Touhou: the Embodiment of Scarlet Devil*, I noticed in the summary statistics of a play that the game keeps track of your overall `Slow` percentage. I've found that using `Slow` definitely helps me with fine tuning my movement when fighting bosses, so I'm trying to force myself to use it more often to help me get through tough battles (my tendency to forget to use my bombs is another matter entirely).

However, is this detrimental to how the game calculates my score? Is using `Slow` a bad habit to form?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Holding shift for focused movement does not affect your score.

The "Slowdown rate" percentage on the score page shows how often the game slowed down (e.g. due to a slow computer), rather than the amount of time spent holding shift. It's mentioned for comparison to other players' high scores, because a high slowdown would give the player an advantage.

Comment: Oh, gotcha, that makes sense. So is it the % of time that the FPS dropped below 60 then?

Comment: Exactly the case.

Comment: Actually its your average FPS offset from 60, lets say you have 60 FPS for half the time and 59FPS the other half, your average is 59.5. 0.5/60 = 0.0083, which means about 0.83% slowdown rate